# Determine if where in clause in select query did not return a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL statement which is searching the database for a few records.

```
SELECT UserName
     , Location
FROM People_DB
WHERE UserName IN ('Nick', 'Jack', 'Robert')
```

The first two names ('Nick', 'Jack') exist in the People_DB and my query returns that information however it does not return 'Robert' since it does not exist in my database.

Is there a way to return 'Robert is not in People_DB' in the query result set?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

there is no straight way of doing this.

You can use something like this

```
drop table #temp

select 'Nick' as  UserName into #temp
union select 'Jack' 
union select 'Robert'

SELECT t.UserName,isnull(b.UserName,'Doesn''t exists',b.Location 
FROM #temp t
left join People_DB b on t.UserName = b.UserName
WHERE b.UserName IN ('Nick', 'Jack', 'Robert')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a "table" with the list of names.  That is the only way to get them back in the result set.

If your databases supports the `values()` constructor, I would recommend:

```
SELECT u.UserName, p.Location
FROM (VALUES ('Nick'), ('Jack'), ('Robert') ) v(UserName) LEFT JOIN
     People_DB p
     ON p.UserName = v.UserName;
```

I should note that alternative solutions are available in almost any database that doesn't support `VALUES`.  For instance:

```
SELECT u.UserName, p.Location
FROM (SELECT 'Nick' as UserName UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Jack' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Robert'
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     People_DB p
     ON p.UserName = v.UserName;
```

A `NULL` location is probably sufficient indication that the name is not found.  If you want an actual flag, you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT u.UserName, p.Location,
       (CASE WHEN p.UserName IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as in_list_flag
FROM (VALUES ('Nick'), ('Jack'), ('Robert') v(UserName) LEFT JOIN
     People_DB p
     ON p.UserName = v.UserName;
```